# In SQL Column Data Converted into Row Data

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have table Called Trn_EmpRetation on that columns are TurnOver and EmpRetension
the data look like below

```
TurnOver    EmpRetension
22           199
```

i want the data look like below

```
Description       TotalNumber
TurnOver           22
EmpRetension       199
```

How to do this in SQL.

Thanks
Basit.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is sufficient:

```
SELECT x.Description, x.TotalNumber FROM
(
    SELECT Description = 'TurnOver',
           TotalNumber = SUM(TurnOver)
    FROM dbo.Trn_EmpRetation
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT Description = 'EmpRetension',
           TotalNumber = SUM(EmpRetension)
    FROM dbo.Trn_EmpRetation
) x
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/51d40/1/0)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`UNPIVOT`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (TurnOver INT, EmpRetension INT);
INSERT @T VALUES (22, 199);

SELECT  uptv.[Description], uptv.TotalNumber
FROM    @T AS t
        UNPIVOT
        (   TotalNumber
            FOR [Description] IN ([Turnover], [EmpRetension])
        ) AS uptv;
```

If you want a SUM, then simply use `SUM` and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT  uptv.[Description], TotalNumber = SUM(uptv.TotalNumber)
FROM    Trn_EmpRetation AS t
        UNPIVOT
        (   TotalNumber
            FOR [Description] IN ([Turnover], [EmpRetension])
        ) AS uptv
GROUP BY uptv.[Description];
```

Comment: The question did not mention any sums, or duplicates... If that was required though I would still use UNPIVOT but just add `SUM/GROUP BY` - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d66d5/2 - This avoids multiple table scans.

Comment: No, but repetition seems pointless, all the more with a column `TotalNumber`.